# Apache cannot be runned: another Web server use the Web port or port is blocked by firewall

Tags: apache, easyphp

When starting EshyPHP, it shows ALERT "Apache cannot be runned: another Web server use the Web port or port is blocked by firewall."

Can anyone suggest solution for this type of issue?

Thanks
Anil

Answer (score 0):

change the port Apache use to 8080 if the case is running on Port 80...

Comment: Hi AndrewDev,  just added Port 8080 in "httpd.conf" file PATH : "C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP5.2.10\conf_files" . But right now I seem EasyPHP shows "Pending" mode. Unable to run server.

Comment: Right now start wamp server and its working, but in the future, I may need to use EasyPHP.

Answer (score 0):

The issue resolve with the follwing.
First I changed the Port 8080 in "httpd.conf" file PATH : "C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP5.2.10\conf_files".

Then following these steps solve the problem:

1). from EasyPHP icon right click -> properties
2). select "Compatibility" tab
3). check "Run this program in compatibility mode for:" and select Windows 7